# Ejecutar un metodo en java automaticamente al iniciar mi JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, class

Deseo saber donde puedo ejecutar un método que he creado, que cargue unos datos al JFrame para poder darle uso...

en este caso tengo un Combo Box que deseo rellenar con los nombres de las personas disponibles, el caso es que tengo un metodo ceosAvailables(), pero no se donde ponerlo para que se ejecute automaticamente al iniciar el proyecto, o para que se ejecute ¿en que clase puedo agregarlo?

```
public class frmDataManager extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 /**
  * Creates new form frmDataManager
  */
   public frmDataManager() {
    
     initComponents();

     //???
    
   }
```

... donde puedo ejecutar o "poner" la siguiente funcion ***this.ceosAvailables*** para que se inicie apenas "abra" la app

```
private void ceosAvailable(){
    
    LinkedList<ClsEmployee> listCeos = this.ctlCompany.ceosAvailables();
    
    for (ClsEmployee employee : listCeos) {
        
        cbCEOEmployeeCompany.addItem(employee.getName());
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar el método [`addWindowListener(WindowListener)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowListener(java.awt.event.WindowListener)) de la clase `java.awt.Window`, pasándole un `WindowAdapter` que implemente el método [`windowOpened(WindowEvent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html#windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)).

De esta forma el método (o cualquier otro código) que deseas se ejecutará al abrirse la ventana.

```
public class frmDataManager extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form frmDataManager
     */
    public frmDataManager() {
        initComponents();

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                ceosAvailable();
            }
        });
    }
}
```